# Line break not getting preserved in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLt (version - `<?xml version="1.0", stylesheet version="2.0">`). I have a node in XML that is having text with line break. When XSLT is parsed I got the output in a single line and not in paragraphs as expected.

My XML

```
<NotificationNotesFromHaulier>
 This is VR1 application.
 STGO Cat2 configuration.
 Test ?
</NotificationNotesFromHaulier>
```

My XSLT

```
<xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ns1:NotificationNotesFromHaulier !=''">

              <xsl:if test="contains(ns1:NotificationNotesFromHaulier, '##**##')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(ns1:NotificationNotesFromHaulier, '##**##')"/>
              </xsl:if>

              <xsl:if test="contains(ns1:NotificationNotesFromHaulier, '##**##')=false()">
                <xsl:value-of select="ns1:NotificationNotesFromHaulier" />
              </xsl:if>

            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              There are no notes
            </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
```

The output shown is as below

```
This is VR1 application. STGO Cat2 configuration. Test ?
```

Expected output(I want as below from XSLT)

```
 This is VR1 application.
 STGO Cat2 configuration.
 Test ?
```

Comment: Can you share your optimal xslt implementation (e.g. initial 6-7 lines or header or the matching template) ? That will help to recognize the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hi I have updated the description part check it @Vebbie

Comment: Your expected output is indeed your actual output:  [Proof](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYit)